# How do I show that the tangent to the parabola y=x^2 at a point (x0,y0) other than the vertex has x-intercept at 1/2x0

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I tried to find the equation of the line because the slope to the tangent is 2x0 also upon finding the equation of the line I set y to be zero but the x intercept didn't turn out to be 1/2x0
this problem is from George F Simmons book calculus with analytic geometry

Comment: If you did not get $\frac1{2x_0}$, then *what* did you get? And *how* did you get it?

Comment: I got stuck at y=2x0((x-x0)+y0

Comment: Did you not realize that $y_0= x_0^2$?

Comment: I just realized that but I ended up having x=x0/2x0 but i doubt thats equivalent to 1/2x0 maybe theres smething wrong in my computation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative of $y= x^2$ is $y'= 2x$ so the slope of the tangent line at $x= x_0$ is $2x_0$.  $y= x_0^2$ there so the tangent line at $x= x_0$ is $y= 2x_0(x- x_0)+ x_0^2$.

The x-intercept is where $y= 2x_0(x- x_0)+ x_0^2= 0$.

Solving that for x, $2x_0(x- x_0)= -x_0^2$.
$x- x_0= -\frac{x_0^2}{2x_0}= -\frac{1}{2}x_0$.

$x= x_0- \frac{1}{2}x_0= \frac{x_0}{2}$.
(NOT $\frac{1}{2x_0}$!)